# How to find the number of possible configurations in this example?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

This is a problem from doing one way ANOVA, see image below that shows the possible configures of three sub population distributions when the null hypothesis of equal mean for all sub population is rejected (and not rejected being the bad quality figure at the bottom).

[3 subpopulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EA8p.png)

For 2 sub populations there are 3 possible configurations
For 3 there are 12 (as shown in image above),
How may one find the number of possible configurations for n number of sub populations?

I tried thinking of the problem as finding the number of possibilities that each box on the plot can be at. Etc top, middle and bottom; but I then would need to subtract two configures of when all of them are at the top and bottom as that would be the same contextually as when they are all in the middle.

It went like this..

For 2 sub-populations: (3*3)-2 = 7
For 3 sub-populations: (3*3*3)-2= 25

That is way bigger than they are suppose to be, I feel like i am double counting some configurations.

Comment: Oh yep, sorry about that. Could you help me by tell me how you expected there to be 12 ?

Comment: There are six orders in which to list three things: $$\begin{align} & A<B<C \\ & A<C<B \\ & B<A<C \\ & B<C<A \\ & C<A<B \\ & C<B<A \end{align}$$ After that, there are three choices of a subset of size $2$: $$\{A,B\}, \quad \{A,C\}, \quad \{B,C\}.$$ For each of those three, one can have the mean for the corresponding union of two subpopulations either larger or smaller thn the mean for the other subpopulation: $$\begin{align} & A=B<C \\ & A=B>C \\ \\ & A=C<B \\ & A=C>B \\ \\ & B=C<A \\ & B=C>A \end{align}$$ Hence $12. \qquad$

Comment: The Stirling number $\left\{ \begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right\}$ is the number of partitions of a set of size $n$ into $k$ subsets. Thus for example, $\left\{ \begin{array}{c} 5 \\ 3 \end{array} \right\} = 25,$ since there are $25$ partitions: $10$ corresponding to the integer partition $3+1+1$ and $15$ to the integer partition $2+2+1. \qquad$

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & ABC/D/E \\ & ABD/C/E \\ & ABE/C/D \\ & ACD/B/E \\ & ACE/B/D \\ & ADE/B/C \\ & BCD/A/E \\ & BCE/A/D \\ & BDE/A/C \\ & CDE/A/B \\  \\ & AB/CD/E \\ & AB/CE/D \\ & AB/DE/C \\ & AC/BD/E \\ & AC/BE/D \\ & AC/DE/B \\ & AD/BC/E \\ & AD/BE/C \\ & AD/CE/B \\ & AE/BC/D \\ & AE/BD/C \\ & AE/CD/B \\ & BC/DE/A \\ & BD/CE/A \\ & BE/CD/A  \end{align} $$

Comment: For these partitions, there are $3!=6$ orders in which we can list the three subsets into which the whole set of $5$ is partitioned. For example, for $ABC/D/E$ we have $$ \begin{align} & (A=B=C) < D < E \\ & (A=B=C) < E<D \\ & D < (A=B=C) < E \\ & D < E < (A=B=C) \\ & E<(A=B=C)<D \\ & E<D<(A=B=C) \end{align}$$

Comment: Thus the total should be $$ \sum_{k=1}^n \left\{\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array} \right\} \cdot k!. $$ But I don't yet know if there's a good way to simplify that.

Comment: For $n=5,$ we get
$$
1\cdot 1! + 15\cdot2! + 25\cdot3! + 10\cdot4! + 1\cdot5! = 1 + 30 + 150 + 240 + 120 = 541.
$$
(This includes the one case in which the null hypothesis is true. Doing that with $n=3$ we would get $13$ rather than $12.$)

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelHardy for your detailed and dedicated explanation ! The simplification would be good enough! Thought the problem can be solved with just permutations and combinations without partitions; thanks for opening a new light on my view of them.

Comment: See also my answer posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) is the answer.

(See also my comments under the question.)

Comment: This may also be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_method $\qquad$

Comment: Much thanks again Michael; have gone through all the comments, 10/10 explanation.